# How to be able to use System Entity, in fulfillment, in Dialogflow?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am getting undefined, when using agent.parameters.geo-country while using the System entity @Sys.geo-country.

This is the error I am getting.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-rP9rkvOB3Wm0KyGn846iFbMBFb2Iu9c/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1):

JSON property syntax (`x.y.z`) doesn't like the dash. In order to get around that, you can use the alternative bracket syntax (`x['y']['z']`)

In your case, you could use `agent.parameter['geo-country']`.

Another thing you can do instead is look at the *name* of the paramter, and change it if you want.

For example, in the case below, the entity type is `@sys.any`, but I've named it to `search`. This means I could instead use `agent.parameter.search` which may be more useful to me.

[image]